# Join strings inside a list depending on criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in the following format,

```
my_list = ['value1', 'value2#', 'value3#', 'value4', 'value5#']
```

I'm hoping to join the values up until the #, thanks

```
new_list = ['value1value2#' 'value3#' 'value4value5#']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine string util `endswith('#')`:

```
my_list = ['value1', 'value2#', 'value3#', 'value4', 'value5#', 'value6']
new_list = []

cur = ''
for s in my_list:
    cur += s
    if s.endswith('#'):
        new_list.append(cur)
        cur = ''

if cur != '':  # add the rest
    new_list.append(cur)
```

output:

```
['value1value2#', 'value3#', 'value4value5#', 'value6']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can join everything and split it by "#"

first - your list has wrong format, you missed commas:
correct way would be:

```py
my_list = ['value1', 'value2#', 'value3#', 'value4', 'value5#']
```

if you not correct that, your list will concatenate (join) strings inside, so you will have 3 values instead of 5.

second - if it doesnt matter if word is ending with "#" then you can for example join everything and split it by "#":

```py
[s+"#" for s in "".join(my_list).split("#") if s]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 my_list = ['value1', 'value2#' 'value3#' 'value4', 'value5#']
 [item+"#" for item in "".join(my_list).split("#")]
```

output : `['value1value2#', 'value3#', 'value4value5#']`

Comment: If the last value in `my_list` doesn't end in `#` you lose the final value from the answer. See Damien's answer for the solution.

Comment: Yes, I missed that case. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I've also realised that if the last value in `my_list` doesn't end in `#` then Damien's answer will add one! This question is a good example of how hard it can be to code something that appears very simple.